# why delete and destroy methods not deleting model - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to delete record from database I had write this code :

```
Route::get("/delete-student/{id}" , function ($id)
{
    $student = \App\Student\Student::find($id);
    $success = $student->delete();
    return ["success" => $success];
});
```

the result is `ture` but the record is still in database , I also tried this

```
$student = \App\Student\Student::destory($id);
```

but the record still not deleted

here is my student model

```
class Student extends Model
{
    protected $table = "student";
}
```

Comment: Are you use softdelete in Student model ?

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd No

Comment: @EmadAl-Kabi have you checked `$student` object value ?  it has value or not ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i had run to the same problem  , the issue was because of the name of columns in my schema

laravel assume that each table has a primary key column named **"id"** , 
**so** if your primary key is not identical to **"id"** with lowercase you should override that by adding `$primaryKey` property to your model like this

```
protected $primaryKey = “YOUR_EXACT_KEY” ; //in my case was “Id”
```

Comment: thanks my friend , that solve the problem , my primary key called "ID"

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this :

```
Route::get("/delete-student/{id}" , function ($id)
{
    $student = \App\Student\Student::find($id);
    $success = $student->forceDelete();
    return ["success" => $success];
});
```

Hope this work for you !!!

Comment: same issue , return `true` but record still not deleted

Answer (score 0):

Instead of find and delete you can directly delete the rows as follows

```
Route::get("/delete-student/{id}" , function ($id)
{
    $success = \App\Student\Student::where('id',$id)->delete();

    return ["success" => $success];
});
```

This will work in your case.

Comment: If you want to make it on 1 row, you can destroy it without retrieving the model with: \App\Student\Student::destroy($id);